# rsync all subdirs with a given name, at whatever depth in the tree

Tags: backup, rsync, directory-structure

I have several subdirs named `admin` in my tree, at various depths.
I mean to rsync all of them (keeping the original depth and names of parents thereof), and exclude the rest of the tree.
What should the contents of file `rsync_include.dat` be?
I am using command

```
[dir1]$ rsync --recursive --update --include-from="rsync_include.dat" --exclude="*" ./ remote:~/dir1/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following options should make an archive copy of any "admin" directory (and contents), and nothing else:

```
rsync -av --include="/admin/" --include='*/' --exclude="*" source/ destination/
```